# Wrong use of bind variable in WHEN of a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sqlplus

I'm fairly new in SQL and I'm trying to set up a **TRIGGER** for an exercise I have. I can't seem to find the solution. Here is the code:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER C3
BEFORE UPDATE OF rate ON Magazines
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN(:NEW.rate < :OLD.rate*0.75)
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.rate < 0 THEN
        :NEW.rate = 0;
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003, 'Rate should never be below 0.');
    ELSE
        :NEW.rate = :OLD.rate*0.75;
END;
/
```

When I try to compile, it shows me this error :
`Non valid use of bind variable in WHEN of a trigger`

I tried to remove the `:` before `NEW` and `OLD` but instead it gives me another compiler error.

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What happens when you add the missing `END IF;`?

Comment: Same error as without the END IF; :(

Answer (score 2):

The assignment operation in pl/sql is :=

```
CREATE TRIGGER C3
BEFORE UPDATE OF rate ON Magazines
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN(:NEW.rate < :OLD.rate*0.75)
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.rate < 0 THEN
        :NEW.rate := 0;
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003, 'Rate should never be below 0.');
    ELSE
        :NEW.rate := :OLD.rate*0.75;
END;
```

Comment: It stills giving me the error of `Wrong use of bind variable in WHEN of the trigger` :(

Answer (score 0):

You first need to remove the colons from the WHEN clause only. Then you will also need colons in front of the equals signs for assignment in the trigger body.

```
CREATE TRIGGER C3
BEFORE UPDATE OF rate ON Magazines
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN(NEW.rate < OLD.rate*0.75)
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.rate < 0 THEN
        :NEW.rate := 0;
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003, 'Rate should never be below 0.');
    ELSE
        :NEW.rate := :OLD.rate*0.75;
END;
/
```

Per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/appdev.11203/e17126/triggers.htm):

> In the trigger_body of a simple trigger or the tps_body of a compound trigger, a correlation name is a placeholder for a bind variable. Reference the field of a pseudorecord with this syntax:
>
> :pseudorecord_name.field_name
>
> In the WHEN clause of a conditional trigger, a correlation name is not a placeholder for a bind variable. Therefore, omit the colon in the preceding syntax.